# step-by-step creation of models with accumulation of predictors vs GridSearch

Tags: r, dataset, predictive-modeling, statistics, linear-regression

Can you please tell me if step linear models of the independent variable "ols_step_both_p()" (R) are possible with the accumulation of predictors in the amount of 58, 220 and 299, naturally with the Bonferoni corrections, which are also accumulated? can all intermediate results be analyzed in the article or not? or is it allowed to publish only the result of one stage (any)?

Can not understand GridSearch (and the like):

```
rf <- RFTrainer$new()
gst <-GridSearchCV$new(trainer = rf,
                       parameters = list(n_estimators = c(100),
                                         max_depth = c(5,2,10)),
                                         n_folds = 3,
                                         scoring = c('accuracy','auc'))
data("DATA1")
gst$fit(DATA1, "pc2")
```

Output:

```
[1] "entering grid search"
[1] "In total, 3 models will be trained"
> gst[["trainer"]]
<RFTrainer>
  Public:
    always_split: NULL
    class_weights: NULL
    classification: 1
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    criterion: gini
    fit: function (X, y) 
    get_importance: function () 
    importance: impurity
    initialize: function (n_estimators, max_depth, max_features, min_node_size, 
    max_depth: 10
    max_features: 17
    min_node_size: 1
    n_estimators: 298
    predict: function (df) 
    seed: 42
    verbose: TRUE
  Private:
    trained_model: ranger
```

Please help me write code for a linear dependency model on 297 predictors (and if possible + 2 more categorical predictors)

Comment: Welcpme to DataScienceSE. Your main question is not clear. I think that the error is due to something wrong in the data, my guess is that it's probably not loaded at all. Usually the function `data()` is used to load a predefined dataset, are you sure that `DATA1` is available in this way? Probably not. You can check by looking if your variable `DATA1` contains anything.

Comment: O. yes. thanks, Erwan

Comment: and what now? Where are the desired models? (result above)

Comment: The model is the variable returned. You can use the `predict` function to apply it to your test set: `gst$predict(mytestdataframe)`.

Comment: OUTPUT: Error: attempt to apply non-function

Comment: Sorry I skipped a step, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

An example of using the best parameters resulting from `GridSearchCV`:

```
library(superml)
library(caret)

data("iris")
train_indexes <- sample(nrow(iris),.75*nrow(iris))
trainset <- iris[train_indexes,]
testset <- iris[-train_indexes,]

rf <- RFTrainer$new()
gst <-GridSearchCV$new(trainer = rf,
                       parameters = list(n_estimators = c(100),
                                         max_depth = c(5,2,10)),
                       n_folds = 3,
                       scoring = c('accuracy','auc'))

gst$fit(trainset, "Species")

best_n_estimators <- gst$best_iteration()$n_estimators
best_max_depth <- gst$best_iteration()$max_depth

final_model <- RFTrainer$new(n_estimators=best_n_estimators,max_depth=best_max_depth)
final_model$fit(trainset,"Species")
predicted <- final_model$predict(testset)
```

Comment: predicted
 [1] -1.31131777096018   -0.0797630909933221 -0.0797630909933221 -0.0797630909933221 -0.0797630909933221 -0.0797630909933221 -0.0797630909933221
 [8] -1.66649824502289   1.58178181526856    1.58178181526856    0.360018099360457   0.51779663853206    0.51779663853206    0.51779663853206   
[15] 0.51779663853206    0.51779663853206    0.51779663853206    -0.535101657113798  1.62351601157687   
55 Levels: -2.70155437579942 -2.63702360526253 -2.6164393648256 -1.66649824502289 -1.59458729604742 -1.31131777096018 ... 2.76682239205511

Comment: Thank you, Erwan, but I want a model, like pc2= a_1*X_1 + a_2*X_2 + a_3*X_3 ……. a_n*X_n + b                maybe i was not clear, sorry

Comment: or   X_1,X_2,X_3 …

Comment: @ЕгорКозлов as I said at the beginning, your question is not very clear. Why do use a Random Forest model in your code if you want linear regression? Also I don't understand why you use GridSearchCV in this case, since as far as I know there's no hyper-parameter to optimize with linear regression.

Comment: Sorry, I am an inexperienced statistician. I misunderstood https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r493.pdf The main problem is that with the gradual addition of variables to the model, the reliable components of the models change due to the negative interaction between the variables and the increasing Bonferroni correction factor to p-value

Comment: I'm not very good for theoretical statistics stuff (and I'm not going to read the full paper), but as far as I understand this is similar to the problem of redundant independent variables. So are you trying to observe an example of this problem? As far as I know this is not related to grid search, grid search is simply about trying different combinations of values, usually  for a set of hyper-parameters, and pick the combination which gives the highest performance,

Comment: no, my explanatory variables are not completely redundant. these are average monthly temperatures and precipitation, geographic distances and coordinates, insect species. morphological parameters of bats are dependent. Only precipitation data remained unanswered, other types of variables responded partially. but all together it's still 250 variables that interact with each other in different ways and lose reliability with the Bonferoni correction